# Echoscu Failed: Data Dictionary Missing

Tags: docker, tls1.2, dcmtk, orthanc-server

I am running Orthanc Server using docker-compose file and attempting to connect to DICOM Server using TLS connection.More details here https://groups.google.com/g/orthanc-users/c/6gNCOVwTc6c.
I downloaded the source code from github for dcmtk 3.6.6 (https://github.com/DCMTK/dcmtk). Followed the instruction for build and built dcmtk 3.6.6 on my debian 10 system. I added the "dcmtk-3.6.6-install/usr/local/bin/" folder to PATH using export PATH command.

After that I attempted to connect to the docker container using the command `echoscu -v -aet ORTHANCA localhost 4242 +tls orthanc-a-server-key.pem orthanc-a-server-crt.pem +cf trusted-crt.pem`.
I received the following error log:

```
E: DcmDataDictionary: Cannot open file: /usr/local/share/dcmtk/dicom.dic
W: no data dictionary loaded, check environment variable: DCMDICTPATH
I: Requesting Association
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)
I: Sending Echo Request (MsgID 1)
E: Echo Failed: 0006:0213 Data dictionary missing
E: Echo SCU Failed: 0006:0213 Data dictionary missing
I: Aborting Association
```

I added "dcmtk-3.6.6-install/usr/local/share/dcmtk/" to PATH and checked using `echo $PATH` that its been added correctly and in that path dicom.dic file is present. Its present however I am getting the same error as above.

In the docker terminal logs I get the following messages for the same

```
orthanc-a-server_1  | I0123 16:14:23.498902 CommandDispatcher.cpp:332] (dicom) Association Received from AET ORTHANCA on IP 192.168.7.1
orthanc-a-server_1  | I0123 16:14:23.499024 main.cpp:318] Incoming connection from AET ORTHANCA on IP 192.168.7.1, calling AET ANY-SCP
orthanc-a-server_1  | I0123 16:14:23.499142 CommandDispatcher.cpp:663] (dicom) Association Acknowledged (Max Send PDV: 16372) to AET ORTHANCA on IP 192.168.7.1
orthanc-a-server_1  | I0123 16:14:23.499831 CommandDispatcher.cpp:917] (dicom) Finishing association with AET ORTHANCA on IP 192.168.7.1: Peer aborted Association (or never connected)
orthanc-a-server_1  | I0123 16:14:23.499917 CommandDispatcher.cpp:930] (dicom) Association Aborted with AET ORTHANCA on IP 192.168.7.1
```

What am I missing here or doing wrong?

Comment: In addition to what "MrBean Bremen" wrote: Following the build instructions, you should also call "make install" and specify the installation path during "configure" (aka as "--prefix") if needed. Then the "dicom.dic" file would be loaded from the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DICOM dictionary is not found, meaning that probably something in the build/installation went wrong.

There are 2 possibilities to include the DICOM dictionary:

- compile it into the library (default under Windows)
- install it and point the environment variable `DCMDICTPATH` to its location (default under Posix)

From the documentation:

> The built-in approach offers the advantage that a binary will not have to
> load any information from a separate file which may get lost or or used in an
> outdated version.  Loading the dictionary content from a separate file,
> however, has the advantage that application programs need not be recompiled
> if additions or corrections are made to the data dictionary.

The related information can be found in the dcmtk sources under `dcmdata/docs/datadict.txt`, there is also an [online version](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/file_datadict.html) of the file.

In short, for non-Windows systems:

To compile the dictionary into the library:

- with autoconf, use the options `--enable-builtin-dict` and `--disable-external-dict`
- with CMake, use `DCMTK_ENABLE_BUILTIN_DICTIONARY`

To use the separate dictionary:

- use the default build options and make sure that use the `install-libs` option; in this case `dicom.dic` will be installed into the default location (under `<datadir>`) and should be found; for this, you should call "make install" and specify the installation path during "configure" (aka as "--prefix") if needed
- if you want to use your own dictionary, or for some reason want to move the dictionary elsewhere, you have to set `DCMDICTPATH` to the location of that dictionary, e.g.:

```
setenv DCMDICTPATH $HOME/dicom.dic
```

*Update:* Added instructions from comment by Jörg Riesmeier.